# Joomla 3 backend column sorting

Tags: sorting, joomla

I trying to learn component building in Joomla 3, and I am reading this Manual:
[Developing MVC component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_ACL)

I have installed this component:
[Component](https://github.com/scionescire/Joomla-3.2-Hello-World-Component/archive/step-14-adding-ACL.zip)

And i have a problem:
There is in component backend message section few columns, they have sorting elements. When I try to sort by "id" or "published" it still sorts by name.
Where is error? Thanks before!

Comment: You installed it as is and it doesn't sort?

Comment: Yes, this is example from manual, it sorts, but only by "name" field, even if you press sort on "published" it will display "arrows" on published but sorts by name.

Comment: Please link to the source not to an archive, i was not happy to get a download I know nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck creating your component using the [Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com) and then trying to sort on your columns. Then when you have verified that it works, you can look in the generated code and see why it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the model file __construct function you need to define fields for sorting filters and then check it will surely sort by id and published.

Here I am providing sample code.
File: model->helloworld.php

```
public function __construct($config = array()) {
    if (empty($config['filter_fields'])) {
        $config['filter_fields'] = array(
            'id', 'a.id',
            'name', 'a.name',
            'published', 'a.published',

        );
    }
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```